# Document.querySelector returns a NULL value - script is at bottom of page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the patientNumber (ClinicA100-PF-TR1-P1) using querySelector. I keep getting a NULL value.  The patientNumber is at the top of the page and the script is at the bottom.  Even after the page is loaded, I click a button that runs the function and it still returns a NULL value.

Here is a screenshot of the selectors (https://recordit.co/IypXuuXib0)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPatientNumber(){  
    var patientNumber = document.querySelector("patientNumber");

console.log(patientNumber);
console.log("hello");
return patientNumber;
}

var patientNumber = getPatientNumber();
console.log(patientNumber);
_kmq.push(['identify', patientNumber]);
</script>
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

---

ADDITIONAL HTML INFORMATION:

I am using Caspio (database management software) to create this HTML code.  I don't know if that may be the cause of the issue.  Here is the HTML CODE.

```
<p class="sponsorName" id="sponsorNameID">[@authfield:User_List_Sponsor_Name]</p>
<p class="clinicNumber" id="clinicNumberID">[@authfield:User_List_Site_Number]</p>
<p class="protocolNumber" id="protocolNumberID">[@authfield:User_List_Protocol_Number]</p>
<p class="patientNumber" id="patientNumberID">[@authfield:User_List_Patient_Number]</p>
```

Comment: Could you please include the sample HTML as code-formatted text in the question?

Comment: `patientNumber` is a class so you should have `".patientNumber"`.

Comment: I have tried ".patientNumber" and "#patientNumberID" and document.getElementById('patientNumberID').  None of these work

Comment: @Cecilia: When I try your exact code but replace `"patientNumber"` with `".patientNumber"` as suggested the code works exactly as I would expect.  Can you update the question to include your attempt and convert the code into a runnable code snippet to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @David - i figured it out.  while the code is at the bottom of the page, and the element is at the top, it is not loaded asynchronously as it comes from a third party database.  i put a delay in the getPatientNumber() and it works now.  Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: @Cecilia: Glad to hear it.  One thing to note is that a delay may be an artificial construct which will Gail if anything delays the asynchronous operation.  You’ll likely want to look for that asynchronous operation and find it’s completed callback, as that would be the better place for this logic.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a dot.

```js
var patientNumberNode = document.querySelector(".patientNumber");
var patientNumber = patientNumberNode.innerText;
```

Comment: I have tried ".patientNumber" and "#patientNumberID" and document.getElementById('patientNumberID'). None of these work.  I added my HTML code as well if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. It should be

```
var patientNumber = document.querySelector(".patientNumber");
```

Why is it failing:
When you use `patientNumber` as the selector, JavaScript looks for an element with a name of `patientNumber`. Since that's not the case, and you are looking for an element with a class of `patientNumber`, you need to use the `.` notation.

---

Addon Suggestion (can be ignored):

Since you are also using IDs, consider using `document.getElementById()` as it is faster than using `document.querySelector()`.

Note that if you use `document.getElementById()`, your `.patientNumber` selector won't work. You need to write it as

```
document.getElementById('patientNumberID');
//ID based on the screenshot of the DOM you've shared
```

Comment: I have tried ".patientNumber" and "#patientNumberID" and document.getElementById('patientNumberID'). None of these work.  I added my HTML code as well if that helps.

Comment: @Cecilia sorry but your question is poorly drafted. Hope you add all the necessary details in the question going forward rather than just writing "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

if you select the item with class".", if you select with id, you should use"#".

```
 var patientNumber = document.querySelector(".patientNumber"); // class select
 var patientNumber = document.querySelector("#patientNumber"); // id select
```

Comment: I have tried ".patientNumber" and "#patientNumberID" and document.getElementById('patientNumberID'). None of these work.  I added my HTML code as well if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

While the code is at the bottom of the page, and the element is at the top, it is not loaded asynchronously as it comes from a third party database. i put a delay in the getPatientNumber() and it works now.